# Can't see AWS billing console despite having the correct IAM roles enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-billing

I have created and set the correct policies to allow me to view the billing page as seen in the following AWS docs page:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_billing.html?icmpid=docs_iam_console#tutorial-billing-step1

and I have tried using the standard policies AWS gives you also but to no avail.

I have got the following 3 policies which are also shown below: AdministratorAccess, Billing, and BillingFullAccess

All of these policies are attatched to the a user group of which my account is a member. There are no other policies attatched to the group or my account.

ADMINISTRATORACCESS:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

BILLING:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aws-portal:*Billing",
                "aws-portal:*Usage",
                "aws-portal:*PaymentMethods",
                "budgets:ViewBudget",
                "budgets:ModifyBudget",
                "ce:UpdatePreferences",
                "ce:CreateReport",
                "ce:UpdateReport",
                "ce:DeleteReport",
                "ce:CreateNotificationSubscription",
                "ce:UpdateNotificationSubscription",
                "ce:DeleteNotificationSubscription",
                "cur:DescribeReportDefinitions",
                "cur:PutReportDefinition",
                "cur:ModifyReportDefinition",
                "cur:DeleteReportDefinition",
                "purchase-orders:*PurchaseOrders"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

BILLINGFULLACCESS:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "aws-portal:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Found the issue was that my colleague had not allowed IAM access to billing from the root account! All sorted now.

Answer (score 12):

You will need to enable Billing console access to IAM Users.

1. Login to aws console with root account (email id and pwd)
2. Click on your account name ( Top Right Corner)
3. Select "Account"
4. Scroll down to "**IAM User and Role Access to Billing Information**" Section
5. Check Mark "**Activate IAM Access**"

[Activate IAM Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L746n.png)

More Details here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_billing.html#tutorial-billing-step1

Answer (score 0):

You first need to enable Billing access option by signing in as a Root user. Once this is done, while still logged in as Root, give billing IAM permission to required user.
Then log in to IAM user & check billing access.
Link for [same](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_billing.html?icmpid=docs_iam_console#tutorial-billing-step1).